JavaFX & Maven: NSException
I created a new project using the Eclipse wizard for a new Maven project.  Here is the primary class:
package org.openjfx.fxhello;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var javaVersion = SystemInfo.javaVersion();
        var javafxVersion = SystemInfo.javafxVersion();

        var label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(label), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}

I also added a launcher class:
package org.openjfx.fxhello;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        App.main(args);
    }
}

And here is the pom:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>fxhello</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <jfx.version>17.0.6</jfx.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${jfx.version}</version>   
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${jfx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${jfx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${jfx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JHUAPL Library for JavaFX that implements
            additional UI controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.jhuapl.javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhuapl-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JFX 3d libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.interactivemesh.importer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jim3dsModelImporterJFX</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.interactivemesh.importer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jimColModelImporterJFX</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.interactivemesh.importer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jimFxmlModelImporterJFX</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.interactivemesh.importer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jimObjModelImporterJFX</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.interactivemesh.importer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jimStlMeshImporterJFX</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.interactivemesh.importer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jimX3dModelImporterJFX</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.fxhello.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

When I ran the App class, I get the error "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application".  I resolved that by adding the Launcher class.  Running Launcher, I get this error:
Apr 17, 2024 10:42:37 AM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2dfbed57'
2024-04-17 10:42:40.325 java[27800:4902791] *** Assertion failure in -[_NSTrackingAreaAKViewHelper removeTrackingRect:], _NSTrackingAreaAKManager.m:1637
2024-04-17 10:42:40.331 java[27800:4902791] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '0x0 is an invalid NSTrackingRectTag. Common possible reasons for this are: 1. already removed this trackingRectTag, 2. Truncated the NSTrackingRectTag to 32bit at some point.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8076f711a __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80721d0b7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007ff8085cdcd8 -[NSCalendarDate initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x00007ff80adcbfe3 -[_NSTrackingAreaAKViewHelper removeTrackingRect:] + 190
    4   libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad87439 Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacApplication__1getMacKey + 3593
    5   libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad8ccb8 RemoteLayerHostRemoteIdInLocal + 3640
    6   AppKit                              0x00007ff80a75b091 -[NSView setFrame:] + 347
    7   libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad8cd15 RemoteLayerHostRemoteIdInLocal + 3733
    8   AppKit                              0x00007ff80a76bec8 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 694
    9   AppKit                              0x00007ff80a76b7fb -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 499
    10  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a74af26 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1460
    11  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a75b091 -[NSView setFrame:] + 347
    12  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a76bec8 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 694
    13  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a76b7fb -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 499
    14  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a74af26 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1460
    15  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a769c03 -[NSThemeFrame setFrameSize:] + 464
    16  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a76930f -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:fromServer:] + 831
    17  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a767da2 -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:fromServer:] + 3089
    18  libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad7ea1f getImage + 6719
    19  libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad7e51c getImage + 5436
    20  libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad7e76b getImage + 6027
    21  libglass.dylib                      0x000000010ad982be Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacWindow__1setBounds2 + 446
    22  ???                                 0x000000011b9eb53a 0x0 + 4758353210
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

In Configure Build Path, Modulepath is set to JRE System Library [JavaSE-17], and Preferences->Java->Installed JREs has the default JRE set as pointing to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home, as expected.  I'm using the latest version of Eclipse (2024-03).  I've deleted ~.m2/repository and let it redownload everything when building, in case there was some kind of corruption issue there.  I am confident I'm forgetting information to share, so please ask and I'll provide.  Thanks for your help!

"Modulepath is set to JRE System Library [JavaSE-17]" This seems wrong, and is probably why the JavaFX modules are being loaded from the classpath instead of the module path. Follow the instructions here to use JavaFX with Eclipse (choose "JavaFX and Eclipse" and then "Modular with Maven").

If you use a launcher class (which you shouldn't need if your configuration is correct) it should probably have Application.launch(App.class, args) instead of App.main(args). I don't think this will make any difference though.

The OpenJFX launch example launches using <yourapplicationsubclass>.main(args), as does JJosé Pereda's example.  Though as, you note, in this case a Launcher class hack is likely not necessary.

I recommend using JavaFX 21+ and JDK 21+, especially if it is an M series Mac.  Also don't use an obsolete version of the javafx-maven-plugin.

@Jewelsea, it's not an option to switch the JavaFX or JDK versions, the code is required to run with 17.  As for the javafx-maven-plugin being obsolete, Eclipse originally set it to 0.0.6, I changed it to 0.0.8 which seems to be the most recent version, didn't solve the problem.

@James_D What should it look like?  I followed the directions at JavaFx and Eclipse -> Modular with Maven.  It originally set it so that Modulepath shows "JRE system library [JavaSE-11]".  I removed that library, then selected Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Workspace Default JRE.  After that I ran Maven -> Update Project, and then opened Configure Build Path again, and it had reverted to "JRE system library [JavaSE-11]"

The javafx-maven-plugin version in your question is 0.0.4, not 0.0.6 or 0.0.8.  But yes, that has nothing to do with your issue and if you have already changed it locally to 0.0.8 then that is currently the latest version anyway.   However, certain versions of JavaFX 17 (I don't recall exactly which ones), do not work correctly with M series Macs or Sonoma, so if that is what you have it may be an issue regardless of your lack of options to switch JavaFX or JDK versions.  Also, you are selecting the JavaFX versions in your project and JavaFX 21 can run on JDK 17 fine.

Did you delete your module-Info.java file?
